# How to initialize a non nullable type?

Tags: c#, null

I'm being told to initializes my struct data but I can't?
`DeviceState` is non nullable:

```
struct XControllers
{
    public XInput.DeviceState device;
    public bool connected;
}

...

XControllers controller;
controller.connected = false;

// can not init device
var previousState = controller.device.State;
```

Error:

> Use of possibly unassigned field 'device'

Comment: Why can't you initialize the `device` field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is constructor the only way to initialize non-nullable properties in a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530963/is-constructor-the-only-way-to-initialize-non-nullable-properties-in-a-class-in)

Comment: `XInput.DeviceState` is possibly a reference type. It is up to you to create an `XInput.DeviceState` instance and assign it to `controller.device`. Neither the compiler nor the .NET runtime will magically create such an instance for you. If you don't, `controller.device` will remain at its default value `null`. And `null` is not an `XInput.DeviceState` instance. Neither will trying to dereference `controller.device.State` succeed, because `null` (that's the value of `controller.device.State`) can't be dereferenced. The compiler noticed that situation in your code and points your nose at it.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins: No, the value simply isn't definitely assigned. This isn't really about nullity - it's about a not-fully-assigned struct. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/c5a4a1d2ecc1d3493bcbe2cc1ac6a03c for an example with a similar error, but no reference types involved.

Comment: @jon skeet, but my issues is that I can not set it to anything. if it were an int I could use 0, but I can't find a default way of giving it a initialization.

Comment: @ada I tried that but I get "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS8370 Feature 'struct field initializers' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 10.0 or greater."

Comment: Well we know nothing about what XInput.DeviceState is here... it feels like this really isn't anything to do with structs, and it's all about a type that you haven't really told us about.

Comment: Well that maybe my issue, wrong question then. Being that I'm confused and the reason I asked the question I too do not know this answer or can figure it out from the API.  Is it best served for me to make a new question specific to xinput?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_xinput/